# how to handle input parameters in QProcess

Tags: qt, parameters, arguments, qprocess

The following simple python code requires three input arguments for 'test.py' (besides 'python' and 'test.py') in command line:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys

def main(argv):
   if (len(sys.argv) < 4):
       print ('argv must be greater than 4')
   else:
     print ('Number of arguments:', len(sys.argv), 'arguments.')
     print ('Argument List:', str(sys.argv))

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Run test.py:

```
C:\>python test.py arg1 arg2
argv must be greater than 4

C:\>python tt.py arg1 arg2 arg3
Number of arguments: 4 arguments.
Argument List: ['tt.py', 'arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3']
```

I use the following simple Qt code, but it fails to produce the above result. Is there a way in Qt to mimic the above command line, i.e. 'python command arg1, ... argN'. 
NOTE: 'python' must be used in this case.

```
   QProcess *qtq = new QProcess();
   QString program("python");
   QStringList arguments("test.py arg1 arg2 arg3");
   qtq->setProgram(program);
   qtq->setArguments(arguments);
   qtq->start();
   qtq->waitForReadyRead();
   qtq->waitForFinished();
   QByteArray s =  qtq->readAll();
   qDebug() << s;
```

Comment: How you know it fails? whats the error or unexpected behavior?

Comment: `QStringList arguments({"test.py" ,"arg1" ,"arg2", "arg3"});`

Comment: @MohammadKanan The parentheses are unnecessary: `QStringList arguments{"test.py", "arg1", "arg2", "arg3"};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
QStringList arguments("test.py arg1 arg2 arg3");
```

That is your problem line. That will create a QStringList with only one string in it, which gets passed as one argument to python. You should instead do:

```
QStringList arguments;
arguments << QString("test.py");   
arguments << QString("arg1");
arguments << QString("arg2");
arguments << QString("arg3");
```